# How to resolve Laravel 7 Page Expired ( 419 )

Tags: ajax, laravel, session, redis, laravel-7

After several weeks of following different approaches on how to resolve this, I still get the page expired from time to time.
I am currently saving my sessions using Redis which I installed on the server(Linux) and I also installed Redis in my Laravel application i.e. website.com(Production) and staging.website.com(Staging). I also grant access to the following folders

1. chmod -R 755 storage
2. chmod -R 644 bootstrap/caches

And also cleared cache. I have csrf in my header and in all my form

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And  I set up the ajax csrf_token like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Session driver:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
```

Here is my config/session.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'redis'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => 'default',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc", "memcached", or "dynamodb" session drivers you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => null,

];
```

Here is my config/database file for Redis

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
            'async' => true,
            'persistent' => true,
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],
```

The session domain is currently using webiste.com for both domain and its sub-domian: staging.website.com.

```
SESSION_DOMAIN = '.website.com';
```

Users repeatedly request for ajax calls most of the time. Any possible approach on how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: deleted cache? maybe composer is using the old view

Comment: I have a little change in my mind, if you could apply and check if it works for you. In your ajax comment your `$.ajaxSetup` whole portion. And inside `data: { a:a,b:b,_token:@json(csrf_token()) },` and check, because with repeated ajax request the token get expires in your case. `a:a,b:b` i am just assuming your form fields

Comment: @Berto99 I have not deleted cache at all

Comment: @OdehDaniel no problem, check my answer

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I This how I used the ajax `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
    },
    cache: false,
    error: function (x, status, error) {
        if (x.status == 500) {
            console.log("Something went wrong, Please report this to the administrator.");
        }
    }

});`

Comment: @OdehDaniel how are you passing the data in your ajax ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I did not pass any data, I just followed the documentation [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `csrf` field's name should be `_token`:

```
'_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

and put it in the request body, not in the headers, like this:

```
$.post(
    '/url',
    {
        '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        ...

    }
).done(function(data ){...});
```

Comment: @OdehDaniel no, otherwise you won't be able to inject it in the request content (you can remove it from the header of the request you are doint)